# Error deploying flask app with Pandas to AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

trying to deploy app to EBS but getting errors. The app structure is:
[image]

The files are:
**01_packages.config**

```
packages:  
  yum:
    make: []
    gcc-c++: []
    gcc-gfortran: []
    python-devel: []
    atlas-sse3-devel: []
    lapack-devel: []
    libpng-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []
container_commands:  
  AddGlobalWSGIGroupAccess: 
    command: "if ! grep -q 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}' ../wsgi.conf ; then echo 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}' >> ../wsgi.conf; fi;"
```

**02_app.config**

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

**03_python.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_pip:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

**application.py**

```
from flask import Flask, Response

import json
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/status")
def status():
    data = {'status': 'ok'}
    js = json.dumps(data)
    resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**requirements.txt**

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.11.15
Pandas
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from application import application
```

**Errors:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Thu Jan 12 16:02:15.106232 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 1873] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jan 12 16:02:15.134727 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1873] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jan 12 16:02:15.135745 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1873] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jan 12 16:02:15.181883 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1873] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 12 16:02:15.181931 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1873] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Jan 12 16:03:52.703980 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1873] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jan 12 16:03:53.819021 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 2170] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jan 12 16:03:53.848192 2017] [so:warn] [pid 2170] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Jan 12 16:03:53.853287 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2170] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jan 12 16:03:53.854699 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2170] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jan 12 16:03:53.898034 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2170] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 12 16:03:53.898098 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2170] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:24.441902 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2170] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:25.564575 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 17853] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:25.594192 2017] [so:warn] [pid 17853] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:25.599197 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 17853] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:25.600577 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 17853] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:25.638801 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17853] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:25.638853 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17853] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:28.296237 2017] [:error] [pid 17859] [client 127.0.0.1:48206] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:29.299328 2017] [:error] [pid 17860] [client 127.0.0.1:48208] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:30.310453 2017] [:error] [pid 17879] [client 127.0.0.1:48210] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Fri Jan 13 23:12:31.313420 2017] [:error] [pid 17880] [client 127.0.0.1:48212] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Fri Jan 13 23:13:14.723832 2017] [:error] [pid 17883] [client 74.71.99.10:51134] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Fri Jan 13 23:13:14.840052 2017] [:error] [pid 17883] [client 74.71.99.10:51134] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py, referer: 
[Fri Jan 13 23:14:53.812319 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17853] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 13 23:14:54.939628 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 18168] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 13 23:14:54.970873 2017] [so:warn] [pid 18168] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Jan 13 23:14:54.976070 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 18168] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 13 23:14:54.977525 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 18168] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 13 23:14:55.021898 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18168] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 13 23:14:55.021983 2017] [core:notice] [pid 18168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: just added the logs. Thanks